# python sqlite fetchall not returning correct data type

Tags: python, sqlite, fetchall

I am having an issue with having fetchall return being the correct data type. fetchone does work?!?!

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

with con:

```
cur = con.cursor()    
cur.execute("SELECT df1 FROM PLCValues")

rows = cur.fetchall()
#print(rows)
for row in rows:
    print (row)
print(row)
```

Returns

```
================= RESTART: C:/Users/zippo/Desktop/Graphit.py =================
(44.64769744873047,)
(44.691650390625,)
(44.691650390625,)
(44.471900939941406,)
(44.64769744873047,)
```

FETCHONE

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

with con:

```
cur = con.cursor()    
cur.execute("SELECT df1 FROM PLCValues")

rows = cur.fetchone()
#print(rows)
for row in rows:
    print (row)
print(row)
```

Returns:

```
================= RESTART: C:/Users/zippo/Desktop/Graphit.py =================
44.64769744873047
44.64769744873047
```

Comment: What is the type of the `df1` column in the `PLCValues` table?

Answer (score 4):

`cur.fetchall()` returns a tuple of tuples. According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html it seems to be returning the correct type. You might want to iterate through individual tuple to get a single element.